# Finding values and counting occurences in a table

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a function or a macro that lists the different values in a table and how many occurrences of the value is in the table.

For example if i have a table like this logging daily stops for machinery.

```
          |   Day 1    |   Day 2     |    Day 3     |
          |:----------:|:-----------:|:------------:|
Machine 1 |     a      |     a       |   No stop    |
Machine 2 |     d      |     g       |      b       |
Machine 3 |     e      |     c       |   No stop    |
Machine 4 |     g      |     i       |      a       |
Machine 5 |     c      |     a       |      b       |
Machine 6 |     a      |     b       |      c       |
```

(The letters a-i represent different types of stops)

I want to create a list like this.

```
|   Stop     | Occurances |
|:----------:|:----------:|
|     a      |      5     |
|  No stop   |      2     |
|     d      |      1     |
|     g      |      2     |
|     b      |      3     |
|     e      |      1     |
|     c      |      3     |
|     i      |      1     |
```

I have already found a ways to do this on a single single column range i'm having trouble doing this on a multi column range.

Comment: You are building a pivot table. Just record a macro of how you build a pivot table from multicolumn input and read it to learn how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the solution that i found is not a macro/formula i found that the simplest and quickest way to solve this was to unpivot the table.
I did this by selecting the entire table, Data->From Table/Range and in the Power Query Editor Transform->Unpivot Columns.

This gave me all the stops in a single column which was much more manageable.

Using Data->Remove Duplicates i could get the unique stops and could use a simple

```
=COUNTIF(RANGE_TABLE;STOP_NR)
```

to get occurrences of stops.

Answer (score 0):

You could modify the code and try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, cell As Range
    Dim Lastrow As Long, Times1 As Long, Times2 As Long

    'Indicate which sheet you will use
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        'Set the range where all data appears
        Set rng1 = .Range("B2:D7")
        'Loop the range
        For Each cell In rng1
            'Find the last row of the column with the results
            Lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
            'Set the range will all the stops
            Set rng2 = .Range("F2:F" & Lastrow)
            'Count how many times a stop appears in the results
            Times1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng2, cell.Value)
            'If it does appears regord
            If Times1 = 0 Then

                Times2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng1, cell.Value)
                .Range("F" & Lastrow + 1).Value = cell.Value
                .Range("G" & Lastrow + 1).Value = Times2

            End If

        Next cell

    End With

End Sub
```